# Let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Then $f_n \to f$ in measure iff $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Tags: measure-theory

My question is to prove this: Let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Then $f_n \to f$ in measure iff $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

This is a homework question, so if you give just hints for the right approach to the question (for the both directions), I will be very happy. Thanks.

Comment: Write out the definition of convergence in measure when the measure is counting measure.  What happens when the measure of a set is less than $1$?

Comment: @Jonas: That set **really** doesn’t count.

Comment: It will be an empty set am I right? Then the set $E_{n,\epsilon} = \{x: |f_n - f| \geq \epsilon\} = \emptyset$. Then, I can sense that the uniform convergence is related to $E_{n,\epsilon}^c$ but... (Thanks!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- $\Rightarrow$: fix $\delta>0$; we have $\mu\{k\in\Bbb N,|f_n(k)-f(k)|>\delta\}<1/2$ for $n$ large enough. As $\mu(A)<1$ if and only if $A$ is empty, for $n$ large enough and all $k$, $|f_n(k)-f(k)|<\delta$ so $f_n\to f$ uniformly.
- $\Leftarrow$: fix $\delta>0$; and $n_0$ such that $\sup_{k\in\Bbb N}|f_n(k)-f(k)|<\delta$ whenever $n\geqslant n_0$. For $n\geqslant n_0$, what is $\mu\{k\in\Bbb N,|f_n(k)-f(k)|>\delta\}$?

Comment: I know this is quite a long time since this posting, but for the backwards direction, to compare $\mu\{k\in\mathbb{N}|f_n(k)-f(k)|>\delta\}$ to sup$_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|f_n(k)-f(k)|<\delta$, would we have to take the limsup of $\mu\{k\in\mathbb{N}|f_n(k)-f(k)|>\delta\}$?  Or could I just compare them directly, because the measure of that set will never be bigger than $\delta$ by the first line.

Comment: Actually, for $n\geqslant n_0$, $\mu\{k\in\Bbb N,|f_n(k)-f(k)|>\delta\}=0$ which gives immediately the convergence in measure.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you so much for replying on a thread that is a decade old.  I really appreciate it! :)